# resizing image to fit in a div when screen resolution change

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a responsive website with bootstrap, i have a problem fitting the image in their div wrapper when screen resolution change. I have looked up other solution , it is really overwhelming with many info and it is difficult to know which one is suited to my situation .I have tried a few proposed solution none of them did solve my problem.

I inserted image but they seem to have out of border width when the screen resolution was changed. I tried a few solution using css found on the internet it did not solve the problem. I did try using Jquery, it could be solved but i would need a different image for each screen resolution (with my algorithm). I thought there must be a more simple approach if someone can help me in directing to the simple solution i will immensely appreciate.

```
<div class="container  imagegallery" >
    <div class="row imagerow ">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
            <div  class="img-wrapper" id='women-shirts'>
                 <img class= "img-responsive" 
                  src="img/womens-t-shirts.png" alt="womens shirts" />
        </div>
    </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="img-wrapper" id='women-pants'>
      <img class= "img-responsive" 
               src="img/womens-pants.jpg" alt="womens pants"  />
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
if(windows.width<798)
{
     $('#women-pants').empty();
     $('#women-pants').append('<img class= "img-responsive" 
       src="img/womens-pants-mobile.jpg" alt="womens pants"  />');
     $('#women-shirts').empty();
     $('#women-shirts').append('<img class= "img-responsive" 
       src="img/womens-t-shirts-mobile.png" alt="womens pants"  />');

}
else
{
     $('#women-pants').empty();
     $('#women-pants').append('<img class= "img-responsive" 
      src="img/womens-pants.jpg" alt="womens pants"  />');
     $('#women-shirts').empty();
     $('#women-shirts').append('<img class= "img-responsive" 
      src="img/womens-t-shirts.png" alt="womens pants"  />');

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because your image has no defined width.

Give your images a width or max-width property:

```
img{
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```